# How to get posts of given hashtag of public page in facebook with php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on one web app where i need all posts of public page with given hashtag. Is it possible to get? I am using graph api somthing like as follow

```
    $data = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page . '/feed?fields=name,message,picture,created_time,link&access_token=' . $accessToken . '&limit=100');
```

Is it possible that i change this url in a way that will give me what i want ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Hashtag Search, you can only get all feed items and search on your own with PHP.